# theme slide Error with parse error wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have issues with my wordpress website displaying this

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*' in /home/havenopt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/search-and-replace/inc/Page/SqlImport.php on line 218

And also My theme slides no longer displays